# window function-choose the most recent row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I need to select the most recent row based on the Creation Date.
Here is my table:

```
REF X      REF Y            EMLOYEE CREATION DATE
2879074 DLP/2015.01551-B.01 Didier  3/5/2015
2879074 DLP/2015.00841-A.01 Didier  2/5/2015
2879074 DLP/2015.00146-A.01 jacques 1/8/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.07840-A.02         1/6/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.03 diet    6/21/2016
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.03 ext     6/21/2016
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.02 David   10/21/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.02 ieva    10/21/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.02 laetitia10/21/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.02 PLN 10/21/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.01 David   4/14/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.01 ieva    4/14/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.01 laetitia4/14/2015
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.01 PLN    4/14/2015
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.03 Andy    9/6/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.03 Nell    9/6/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.03 stephane9/6/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.02 Andy    2/17/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.02 Nell    2/17/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.02 nicola  2/17/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.02 diet    2/17/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.01 herve   3/10/2015
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.01 nicola  3/10/2015
```

The output should be:

```
Ref x   Ref y   employee           Creation Date
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.03 diet    6/21/2016
2879074 DLP/2014.05967-B.03 ext     6/21/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.03 Andy    9/6/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.03 Nell    9/6/2016
2733407 DLP/2014.00138-B.03 stephane9/6/2016
```

I'm guessing I have to use window function, but I have trouble listing the correct REF Y. Any help would be appreciated
Many thanks

Comment: your most recent row is not clear (to me atleast)

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: posting ddl,dml of tables involved helps others in testing quickly and you can get help faster

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the 5 most recent rows, you would simply do this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [Creation Date] DESC
```

No windowing function required, unless there is more complicated you are trying to achieve.